# Atlas joints documentation. Where to find

Tags: gazebo

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

I am able to control all Atlas joints following tutorials, but the joints names are not always a good enough description to realize which one is which. Is there any document that describes which joints corresponds to which joint name?

Best regards,

LR

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.gazebosim.org/question/1732/atlas-joints-documentation.-where-to-find./) by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on Gazebo Answers with karma: 43 on 2013-03-11

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Gazebo Answers logo]

The best option is probably to run

```
roscd atlas
roslaunch urdf_tutorial display.launch model:=atlas.urdf gui:=True
```

and then play with the sliders to figure out which joint corresponds to which name.

---

Originally posted by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) with karma: 508 on 2013-03-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-03-12**:
Hello, where can i find that tutorial? Using these commands all i get is: [urdf_tutorial] is not a package or launch file name

**Comment by [ThomasK](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/16/thomask/) on 2013-03-12**:
"`sudo apt-get install ros-fuerte-robot-model-tutorials`" ... should get you the package

**Comment by [Luis Filipe Rossi](https://answers.gazebosim.org/users/55/luis-filipe-rossi/) on 2013-03-14**:
Ok, now it is working.
Thank you!